# Padding/Margin/Border On Element Does Not Change DIV Height

Tags: html, css

Here is a very simply jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ryandlf/mSmUv/4/

When an element has a top padding or margin and it sits on the first line within a div, the div does not respect that padding or margin and push the element down. In most cases this isn't an issue, but for example, if I have a button that has a top border and padding the top of the border will be cut off because the div is not taking into consideration the padding value.

Is there a workaround for this other than just blindly setting margins or padding on every container div element and hoping I have added enough to account for any internal element that might be affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your link with class button is not a `block` element, it is `inline` element. Change this default behaviour by adding `dispaly: block` to it and it will work as expected. Proof available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSmUv/5/).

So to sum up, the problem is not with the div - it is the problem with css - inline elements ignore margin and padding because they cannot 'reserve space'.

UPDATE: To answer your comment, [here is the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mSmUv/6/) you might be looking for

Comment: How do I set the width to fit the text in this case?

Comment: float left means everything in the div must have a float element otherwise it won't position properly. Inline block works perfect, but is there a solution for IE7?

Comment: Not really...basically what I meant is that if the div containing say a button has other elements...maybe an image or something and I assign float left to the bottom and not the image, it won't position properly. I would have to add float left to the image too which makes it confusing to arrange elements.

Comment: it's not confusing to use float, this is the standard way of doing it actually. You might use float: right as well if you wish, and combine it with margin to obtain desired spaces. If you have many elements that needs to be positioned you probably would need to group them somehow with divs and assign float: left to such wrappers

Answer (score 2):

The button element is `inline`. To get the desired behavior you can set `display:inline-block`.
Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TRTue/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following to the parent div:

overflow: hidden

I hope it helps!